# Scaling property of Laplace Transform not working

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that $L(f(t)) = F(s) \implies L(f(at))= \frac{1}{a}F(s/a)$  and if $L(1) = 1/s$

- $L(2 \cdot 1) = 1/2 \cdot F(s/2) = 1/2 \cdot 1/(s/2) = 1/s$ but
- $L(2 \cdot 1)  = 2 \cdot L(1) = 2 \cdot 1/s = 2/s$

Why is there a contradiction? What am I missing?

Comment: You laplace transform a function but f(1) and f(2) are constants. Your confusion between functions and constants is probably your problem.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit now it make sense, and still it contradict

Comment: Is 1 the indicator function? If so, then 1(2t) is not 2.1(t).

Comment: @Paul A function of Laplace transform $1/s$ would be $1$ everywhere on which we integrate $f(t)e^{-st}$. So $f$ is the indicator function of (any superset of) $\Bbb R^+$. But we may as well regard it as constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both calculations, you appear to seek the Laplace transform of a function that always returns $2$. Your second calculation is correct. To get $1/2\cdot1/(s/2)$ you'd want a function that multiplies $t$ by $2$ before returning $1$, which is just the original always-$1$ function.

It helps to consider the more general $L(cf(at))=ca^{-1}F(s/a)$, which includes rescaling of not only the argument but also the function's returned value. We must then take care not to confuse $c=2,\,a=1$ with $c=1,\,a=2$.

Comment: oh L(f(2*1)) = L(1) and not L(2*1) which is the confusion thanks